# Calculate the area of overlap of a buffer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, buffer

I am a beginner with GIS. I have used the buffer tool in ArcMap to draw a 1 km buffer around a set of three survey posts. I want to calculate the area of where the buffers overlap. Is there a tool in ArcMap which will allow me to do this?

[image]

Comment: Of course. Look in the Overlay toolbox.

Comment: Hi Vince, Thanks very much for the comment. Could you specify which tool in the Overlay toolbox can be used for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it two steps:
first use Intersection to get the area where all circles overlaps.
Then you can calculate the area of the new polygon. You check out this page if you don't know how to do is https://www.gislounge.com/calculating-polygon-area-in-arcmap/

Comment: Intersect will leave out the parts that only exist in one geometry.  This task requires Union.

Comment: I don't think so Vince - they asked how to calculate the area of overlap, not the total area within any one of the buffers

Comment: Thanks very much for all the comments. I used the intersect tool and it worked great. I merged the three intersects using the merge tool. Then I calculated the geometry of them and divided them by three to get the total overlap area, which seems to have given the correct area.

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Won't happen again!